# select method not producing the right results in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have searched for hours trying to find a solution to this.

I am having problems with this statement. It returns nil but it should return a hash.

```
stats = stats.select("date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance")
```

I've run it in my console as:

```
Stat.select("date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance")
```

Here's the output from the console:

```
Stat.select("date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance")
  Stat Load (0.3ms)  SELECT date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance FROM "stats"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Stat id: nil, date: "2013-01-06">]>
```

The result I am looking for would be a hash with :date => value and :total_attendance => value
like

```
attendance: 31, date: "2013-06-30"
```

I have also tried using

```
Stat.group(:date).sum(:attendance)
```

but it returns a hash with the date as the key and the total attendance as the value.

like so:

```
Sun, 06 Jan 2013=>66, Sun, 13 Jan 2013=>65
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought the first statement would be correct, but the bottom line is I'm looking for the right result.

Comment: could you fix typo? `Stat.select("date", sum(attendance) as total_attendance")` just to make sure that's not your problem

Comment: Oops, sorry about the typo. It was only in my question. The proper statement in my console returns the date but no total_attendance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` statement expects several rows of results, whereas `sum` is a [calculation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#sum) and produces only one result for the entire table (if no `where` statement given). So `sum` should either be used together with `group` or directly on the class level:

```
Stat.sum(:attendance)
```

**Update:**

To get the hash you want just do:

```
Stat.select('date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance').group(:date)
```

If you don't group by date the result will be incorrect.

Comment: So what I am really looking for is to get the select statement to work. Otherwise I have to run a loop and make multiple queries with a resulting performance hit.

Comment: @Dave Olson please try running `Stat.select('date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance').group(:date)`

Comment: Okay... I've tried the statement as you suggest, but it doesn't return any value for total_attendance. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: It does. It will not be visible in console, but you can get it for each item. `Stat.select('date, sum(attendance) as total_attendance').group(:date).collect(&:total_attendance)`.